# not able to run glxdemo from inside lxc container using nvidia

Tags: nvidia, xorg, opengl, lxc

I have created `lxc` container of our custom toolchain that has many packages.
Related to graphics, I have installed `nvidia 367.27` driver using the nvidia installer inside this container(called `mk7icontainer`)

The nvidia driver libraries/binaries are installed at path `/usr/share/nvidia` path inside this container.

I have also installed `mesa` installed in path `/usr` inside container.

I compiled the `glxdemo` source code using the command as:

```
gcc -g glxdemo.c -Wl,--rpath-link,/usr/share/nvidia/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/share/nvidia/lib \
-Wl,--rpath-link,/usr/share/nvidia/lib/tls -Wl,-rpath,/usr/share/nvidia/lib/tls \
-Wl,--rpath-link,/usr/share/nvidia/lib/vdpau  -Wl,-rpath,/usr/share/nvidia/lib/vdpau \
-Wl,--rpath-link,/usr/share/nvidia/lib/xorg/modules -Wl,-rpath,/usr/share/nvidia/lib/xorg/modules \
-Wl,--rpath-link,/usr/share/nvidia/lib/xorg/modules/drivers -Wl,-rpath,/usr/share/nvidia/lib/xorg/modules/drivers \
-Wl,--rpath-link,/usr/share/nvidia/lib/xorg/modules/extensions -Wl,-rpath,/usr/share/nvidia/lib/xorg/modules/extensions -lX11 -lGL -lGLU -lglut -lm -o glxdemo
```

Inside the container, I have

```
DISPLAY=":0"
XAUTHORITY=/root/.Xauthority
```

I am starting the `bash` in the container using below command:

```
sudo lxc-attach -n mk7icontainer --clear-env  -- /usr/bin/bash
```

My host machine is running `Ubuntu 16.0.4` and I installed the same `nvidia 367.27` driver using its installer. It is running fine. I can even run `glxdemo` on host machine without any issues.

However, when I try to run `glxdemo` inside the container ( compiled using above mentioned command), I get the following error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
Value in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  24
Current serial number in output stream:  25
```

anyone got any idea what is wrong here?

I also want to know how to read these errors to narrow down the problem.

Source code for `glxdemo` is :

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glx.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
static void redraw( Display *dpy, Window w )
{
   printf("Redraw event\n");
   glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

   glColor3f( 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 );
   glRectf( -0.8, -0.8, 0.8, 0.8 );
   glXSwapBuffers( dpy, w );
}

static void resize( unsigned int width, unsigned int height )
{
   printf("Resize event\n");
   glViewport( 0, 0, width, height );
   glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
   glLoadIdentity();
   glOrtho( -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0 );
}

static Window make_rgb_db_window( Display *dpy,
                              unsigned int width, unsigned int height )
{
   int attrib[] = { GLX_RGBA,
                    GLX_RED_SIZE, 1,
                    GLX_GREEN_SIZE, 1,
                    GLX_BLUE_SIZE, 1,
                    GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER,
                    None };
   int scrnum;
   XSetWindowAttributes attr;
   unsigned long mask;
   Window root;
   Window win;
   GLXContext ctx;
   XVisualInfo *visinfo;

   scrnum = DefaultScreen( dpy );
   root = RootWindow( dpy, scrnum );

   visinfo = glXChooseVisual( dpy, scrnum, attrib );
   if (!visinfo) {
      printf("Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual\n");
      exit(1);
   }

   /* window attributes */
   attr.background_pixel = 0;
   attr.border_pixel = 0;
   attr.colormap = XCreateColormap( dpy, root, visinfo->visual, AllocNone);
   attr.event_mask = StructureNotifyMask | ExposureMask;
   mask = CWBackPixel | CWBorderPixel | CWColormap | CWEventMask;

   win = XCreateWindow( dpy, root, 0, 0, width, height,
                    0, visinfo->depth, InputOutput,
                    visinfo->visual, mask, &attr );

   printf("\n XCreateWindow successfull \n");
   ctx = glXCreateContext( dpy, visinfo, NULL, True );
   if (!ctx) {
      printf("Error: glXCreateContext failed\n");
      exit(1);
   }

        printf("\n glXCreateContext successfull \n");

   glXMakeCurrent( dpy, win, ctx );

   return win;
}

static void event_loop( Display *dpy )
{
   XEvent event;

   while (1) {
      XNextEvent( dpy, &event );

      switch (event.type) {
         case Expose:
            redraw( dpy, event.xany.window );
            break;
         case ConfigureNotify:
            resize( event.xconfigure.width, event.xconfigure.height );
            break;
      }
   }
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
   Display *dpy;
   Window win;

   dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
        if(!dpy)
        {
                printf("\nError in XOpenDisplay\n");
        }
        printf("\nXOpenDisplay successfull\n");

   win = make_rgb_db_window( dpy, 300, 300 );

   printf("\nmake_rgb_db_window successfull \n");
   glShadeModel( GL_FLAT );
   glClearColor( 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0 );

   XMapWindow( dpy, win );

   event_loop( dpy );
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue.

I had to add `nvidia` device nodes in the `lxc container` config file.

```
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 195:* rwm
lxc.mount.entry = /dev/nvidia0 dev/nvidia0 none bind,optional,create=file
lxc.mount.entry = /dev/nvidiactl dev/nvidiactl none bind,optional,create=file
lxc.mount.entry = /dev/nvidia-modeset dev/nvidia-modeset none bind,optional,create=file
```

Comment: See here for the config file location: https://askubuntu.com/questions/846258/where-are-the-lxc-container-configuration-files-located