# Where are the LXC container configuration files located?

Tags: lxc, lxd

I am working with LXC containers and I am attempting to setup a network configuration but I cannot locate the configuration file. Every piece of documentation or answered question has been for older outdated versions of LXC.

Much of the documentation I found refers to a folder in /var/lib/lxc, but that folder does not exist. Documentation also refers to commands such as "lxc-create" which also do not exist.

I am using LXD to manage my containers instead of libvirt, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are talking about the 'old' LXC containers. In case you are running Ubuntu 16.04 or Ubuntu 16.10, everything is located in the `/var/lib/lxd` folder, also the commands changed.

To get a list of the available commands, execute `lxc help --all` and for deeper information `lxc manpage`. Here you can find additional useful information about the "newer" LXD system containers in Ubuntu :

[Linux Containers - LXD](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/introduction/)
[LXD doc / configuration](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/blob/master/doc/configuration.md)
[The LXD 2.0 Story series](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/03/14/the-lxd-2-0-story-prologue/)

Comment: I don't see config file in /var/lib/lxd. though, there is /var/lib/lxd/containers/<name of the container>/ contains backup.yaml, metadata.yaml, rootf and templates. host and container both are ubuntu 18.04 in my case.

Answer (score 2):

If you installed LXC/LXD using "snap", try looking in the folder

```
/var/snap/lxd
```

That's where I found them all on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS install when I was looking for them.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using multiple locations I find an easy way is

```
lxc storage list
```

which shows the path to each storage pool